# PowerShell Move-Object script task

Tags: windows, powershell, items

I want to create a scheduled script that will move all folder's **.exe** items to another dir.

This is what I tried to do:

```
$folderItems = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Test | where {$_.Extension -eq ".exe"}
```

This is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads> $folderItems

Directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                
-a----         6/4/2018  10:42 PM       10563368 bsplayer272.setup.exe                                               
-a----        5/27/2018   9:46 PM         658488 setup.exe                                                           
-a----         6/4/2018   7:28 PM        2948240 uTorrent.exe
```

But when I try to move them:

```
$folderitems | % {
  Move-Item -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Test\$_.name -Destination D:\Downloads\
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Move-Item : Cannot find path
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Test\bsplayer272.setup.exe.name'
>   because it does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: `Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination D:\Downloads`

Answer (score 0):

- `Move-Item` accepts piped input, so no `ForEach-Object`,`%`needed,
  also not the intermediate variable.
- If you attach the wildcard to the path the where is also superfluous.

---

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Test\*.exe |
    Move-Item -Destination D:\Downloads\
```

Your own command could work if you put it like @Theo's suggestion, or

```
$folderitems | % {
  Move-Item -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Test\'+$_.Name -Destination D:\Downloads\
}
```

or

```
$folderitems | % {
  $_ | Move-Item -Destination D:\Downloads\
}
```

Comment: or.. `$folderitems | Move-Item -Path {$_.FullName} -Destination 'D:\Downloads\'`